# Select one field from a filter in Django

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

I have a quick question: How can I select only one field from my filter form in Django? I'm currently displaying the whole thing:

```
<div class="container">
    <form method="GET" >
        {{ filter.form.Precio|crispy }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Aplicar filtros</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'd like to separe the filter form. I used to do this:

```
{{ form.username }}
```

but it doesn't seem to work...

EDIT: This is filters.py

```
class PubFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
    Precio = django_filters.NumericRangeFilter()
    o = django_filters.OrderingFilter(
        choices=(
            ('-Más nuevo', 'Más nuevo'),
            ('Más nuevo', 'Menos nuevo')
        ),
        fields={
            'Fecha': 'Más nuevo',
        }
    )

    class Meta:
        model = publicaciones
        fields = ['Título', 'Precio', 'Categoría']
        fields ={
            'Título': ['icontains'],
        }
```

Comment: What about `{{ filter.form.username }}`?

Comment: It's what I tried. Maybe it's because I'm not selecting the fields properly. I'll edit and add filters.py

Comment: but you used `{{ form.username }}`, not `{{ filter.form.username }}` (so with `filter.`.

Comment: I wrote that wrong, sorry, watch the new edit

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is it throwing some error? Assuming that the variable *filter* is a dictionary and *form* is a key to that dict. Just use like that

`{{ filter.form.username }}`